# Reference HLSL functions directly in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

I use Compute Shader in Unity for calculations on the GPU. I implemented a lot of functions. But in certain cases, I want to use the function on the CPU because I only need exactly one value and it would be very inefficient to calculate this value on the GPU.

The problem is that I therefore have to implement each function twice. Once in the Compute Shader and once in C#. This makes the code base harder to maintain.

## My Question

Is there a way to reference functions directly in C# when they are defined in a Compute Shader (HLSL)?

## Example

compute shader:

```
float Function(float3 p)
{
    return length(p);
}
```

In C# I have something like this:

```
public static float Function(Vector3 p)
{
    return Vector3.Magnitude(p); 
}
```

But I want something like:

```
using computeShaderCode;
public static float Function(Vector3 p)
{
    return computeShaderCode.Function(p); 
}
```